# NginX "Location" block selection algorithm

Tags: nginx

Since it's possible to define multiple location blocks with different patterns, when Nginx receives a request, it searches for the location block that best matches the requested URI.

The order in which I specify the location blocks in the configuration file is irrelevant. Nginx will search for matching patterns in a specific order:

1. location blocks with the = modifier: If the specified string exactly matches
   the requested URI, Nginx retains the location block.
2. location blocks with no modifier: If the specified string exactly matches the
   requested URI, Nginx retains the location block.
3. location blocks with the ^~ modifier: If the specified string matches the
   beginning of the requested URI, Nginx retains the location block.
4. location blocks with ~ or ~* modifier: If the regular expression matches the
   requested URI, Nginx retains the location block.
5. location blocks with no modifier: If the specified string matches the
   beginning of the requested URI, Nginx retains the location block.

Therefore, in the following case:

```
server 
{
    server_name website.com;
    location /document 
    {
        […] # requests beginning with "/document"
    }
    location ~* ^/document$ 
    {
        […] # requests exactly matching "/document"
    }
}
```

I was told that in this case, the string specified in the fist block now exactly matches the requested URI. As a result, Nginx prefers it over the regular expression.

My question is why? NginX should select the 2nd block (priority 3) because it has better (lower) priority than the 1st block (priority 5).

Can someone please clarify why NginX would still pick the 2nd block?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you get your list from? According to Nginx [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location), there are 4 different cases. I put them in order from least to most priority: 1. prefix location with no modifier; 2. location defined with regular expression; 3. prefix location with ^~ modifier; 4. exact location with = modifier. In your list items 2 and 5 are the same and they define the least "important" case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) on that question:

> To find location matching a given request, nginx first checks locations defined using the prefix strings (prefix locations). Among them, the location with the longest matching prefix is selected and remembered. Then regular expressions are checked, in the order of their appearance in the configuration file. The search of regular expressions terminates on the first match, and the corresponding configuration is used. If no match with a regular expression is found then the configuration of the prefix location remembered earlier is used.

According to documentation nginx must choose regexp location. I've tested it by adding following block to my configuration:

```
location /document
{
    return 405;
}
location ~* ^/document$
{
    return 406;
}
```

And here is the test result, as expected, regexp location used:

```
root@terrty:~# curl -I https://example.org/document
HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
Server: nginx/1.7.10
```

Comment: God, I *love* nginx documentation.